# Time Series Stationarity Proof

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I am new to Time Series, please help with showing why the equation below by taking the second order differencing it will be stationary? $$ Z_t =\beta_0+\beta_1t+\beta_2t^2+\epsilon_t $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi: Second order differencing means use the transformation $Y_t = (1 - L)^2 \times Z_t$ where L denotes the lag operator. So, the question is whether $Y_t$ is stationary if one uses that transformation.

So, $Y_t =  (1 - 2L + L^2) \times Z_{t} = Z_t - 2 Z_{t-1} + Z_{t-2}$.

Then, substitute for $Z_{t-1}$ and $Z_{t-2}$ and it should turn out that the
$Y_t$ does not depend on $t$ which implies that it's mean is constant.
Note that, for this specific model, a constant mean  implies stationarity.

NB: Actually, there are a few different types of stationarity in the time series world but my guess is that the question is referring to the weakest kind which is the one where the response of a model has constant mean and constant variance.

Comment: This is brilliant!!! Thank you very @mlofton.

Comment: thanks but I definitely wouldn't say brilliant. a lot of time series is just knowing notation and terminology. example is "second order differencing". the key is to show that $Y_t$ doesn't depend on $t$ which I left as an exercise for the reader :).